# Delete app data from test device (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to delete the user's login credentials and push notifications permissions from my test iPhone 4.
When I delete the app, it still remembers the user's login credentials, and it doesn't reset the push notification opt-in permissions.

How can I reset this data?

Comment: Could you post the code you use for the user's authentication? Are you using sample code you found somewhere? Please post all relevant information, along with any attempts you've made to fix this issue to get better answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two separate problems.

For the login problem, sounds like you're storing the user's login credentials on the keychain. The only way to wipe this out is to either do it via code, logging out and then deleting the app, or doing a factory reset on the device.

About resetting the push notification status, it's mentioned in an Apple Technical Note here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Scroll down to "Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS"

Comment: you right. i using keychain to store the user login details.
thank you for answer!